# I can't get the content of a specific URL

Tags: php

I can't get the content of this URL (I get a blank page): https://www.euronews.com/api/watchlive.json

I have always used this function and never had problems:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents_curl("https://www.euronews.com/api/watchlive.json"), true); $url = $data['url']; echo $url;
```

Any idea?

EDIT: Unknown problem caused (possibly) by cURL module in Raspbian (Raspberry)

Comment: how did you run the function?

Comment: And what happens when you try? "It doesn't work" is not a valid question.  Also, you have several undefined variables in your function: `$referer`, `$header`, `$useragent`, and `$cookie`

Comment: Please describe what `file_get_contents_curl` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `echo` the function if you want to see the content. I tried this on my end and I got the content. althought I have some undefined variable error because of `$referrer`, `$header`, `$useragent` and `$cookie`. but it runs and get the result. here is how I call the function

```php
echo file_get_contents_curl("https://www.euronews.com/api/watchlive.json");
```

Comment: It seems that my Apache server (for Raspbian) is not working fine. I have tested in a free hosting and it works without problem.
I will install the cURL module again.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes maybe enable some error reporting too you might see more error related to the issue. if my answer helps please dont forgot to up vote tnx

Answer (score 0):

You're getting more than you expect in your function response, so the json_decode is failing. You need to set CURLOPT_HEADER to false instead of 5.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
```

You can verify what you're getting by doing

```
$response = file_get_contents_curl("https://www.euronews.com/api/watchlive.json");
var_dump($response);
$data = json_decode($response, true); 
$url = $data['url']; 
echo $url;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Curiously, my server returns "bool(false)"

... and from my free hosting... "string(175) "{"url":"\/\/euronews-en-p-api.hexaglobe.net\/f146285ee8ee542ccb706320faefa226\/5d5c030d\/euronews\/euronews-euronews-website-web-responsive-2\/en\/stream_info.php?format=hls"}" //euronews-en-p-api.hexaglobe.net/f146285ee8ee542ccb706320faefa226/5d5c030d/euronews/euronews-euronews-website-web-responsive-2/en/stream_info.php?format=hls"

Comment: In that case, you might want to leave the header on and `var_dump($data)` within your function to see what the response headers might be, if any.